# Use Workbench for SQL database saved on Local PC ( Desktop)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm struggling to use the Workbench software for a database saved on my desktop. I do normally work with SQL server online but in our case the client sent us directly the local file.

Do you know how if it is possible?

Thanks 
NC

Comment: yes is possible .. once you have a valid mysql installation just connect mysql  workbench  .. with dbname, user and pwd

Answer (score 0):

create a new database
`create database database_name`

import the '.sql' file provided to you into it
`mysql -u username -p database_name < path/to/database_file.sql`

the database will be visible then.
you can use the workbench gui instead. ensure you have created a new database first then import.

Comment: make sure you're using the same username for creating the database, importing and for workbench connection

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working on workbench for mac. Is the code different?